# Memory Corruption in malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I am having problems with allocation. When I try to allocate my struct variables, it gives me the error of malloc corruption. And I am kind of new at C so, I think I need some help.

More precisely when I try to allocate in this line:

```
g->nos = (no_grafo **)malloc(sizeof(no_grafo*))
```

it gives me the error I am talking about.

There is my line error in the compiler, struct, my code, and my call code:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fffff040801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007fffff089897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fffff1b6b9a "%s\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007fffff09090a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7fffff1b4e0e "malloc(): memory corruption") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007fffff094994 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7fffff3ebc40 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=8) at malloc.c:3738
#5  0x00007fffff0970fc in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=8) at malloc.c:3057
#6  0x0000000000402a2c in grafo_novo ()
#7  0x0000000000402f59 in criaGrafo ()
#8  0x0000000000400ca0 in verifica_criaGrafo ()
#9  0x0000000000401a9b in main ()




struct no_grafos;

typedef struct
{
    int peso_ligacao;     
    struct no_grafos *destino; 
} ligacao;

typedef struct no_grafos
{
    char *nome_user;    
    int tamanho;        
    ligacao **ligacoes;  
} no_grafo;

typedef struct
{
    int tamanho;        /* numero de nos */
    no_grafo **nos;  /* vetor de nos */
} grafo;




grafo* grafo_novo()
{
    grafo* g;

    g = (grafo*)malloc(sizeof(grafo));
    if(g == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    g->nos = (no_grafo **)malloc(sizeof(no_grafo*));
    if(g->nos == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    g->nos = NULL;
    g->tamanho = 0;

   return g;
}

void grafo_apaga(grafo* g)
{

    if(g == NULL)
        return;

    if(g->nos != NULL){
        int i,j;
        for (i =0; i< g->tamanho; g++){
            for(j=0; j< g->nos[i]->tamanho;j++){
                free(g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]);
            }
            free(g->nos[i]);
        }
        free(g->nos);
        free(g);
        g = NULL;
    }

    return;
}


no_grafo * no_insere(grafo *g, char *user) 
{

   if(g == NULL || user == NULL) return NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < g->tamanho; i++){
        if (strcmp(g->nos[i]->nome_user, user) == 0) return NULL;
    }

    no_grafo * no = (no_grafo*)malloc(sizeof(no_grafo));
    if(no == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    no->nome_user = (char*)calloc(strlen(user)+1,sizeof(char));
    if(no->nome_user == NULL){
        free(no);
        no = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        strcpy(no->nome_user,user);
    }

    no->ligacoes = (ligacao**)malloc(sizeof(ligacao*));
    if(no->ligacoes == NULL){
        free(no->nome_user);
        free(no);
        no = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }

    g->nos = (no_grafo **)realloc(g->nos, (g->tamanho + 1) * sizeof(no_grafo *));
    if(g->nos  == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }


    no->tamanho = 0;
    g->nos[g->tamanho] = no;
    g->tamanho++;

    return no;

}

int  cria_ligacao(no_grafo *origem, no_grafo *destino, int peso)
{

    if(origem == NULL || destino == NULL || peso < 1) return -1;

    for(int i=0; i < origem->tamanho; i++){
        if(origem->ligacoes[i]->destino==destino){ // ligacao já existente
            return 0;
        }
    }

    ligacao *liga = (ligacao*)malloc(sizeof(ligacao));
    if(liga == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    liga->destino = destino;
    liga->peso_ligacao = peso;
    origem->ligacoes[origem->tamanho] = liga;
    origem->tamanho++;


    return 0;

}


no_grafo * encontra_no(grafo *g, char *nomeU)
{

    if(g == NULL) return NULL;

    for(int i=0; i< g->tamanho; i++){
        if(strcmp(g->nos[i]->nome_user,nomeU)==0){
            return g->nos[i];
        }
    }


    return NULL;
}


grafo * criaGrafo(tabela_dispersao *td)
{

    if(td == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    grafo * g;
    g = grafo_novo();


    int n[2] = {0}, contador = 0;

    while(td->elementos[contador] != NULL){
        no_grafo *no_remetente = no_insere(g,td->elementos[contador]->msg->remetente);
        if(no_remetente != NULL){
            mensagem ** tabela = tabela_listagem(td,td->elementos[contador]->msg->remetente);
            if(tabela != NULL){
                while(tabela[contador] != NULL){
                    no_grafo *no_destinatario = no_insere(g,tabela[contador]->destinatario);
                    if(no_destinatario != NULL){
                        ligacao2(td,tabela[contador]->remetente,tabela[contador]->destinatario,n);
                        if(n[0] != 0 && n[0] != -1){
                            cria_ligacao(no_remetente,no_destinatario,n[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        td->elementos[contador] = td->elementos[contador]->proximo;
    }

    return g;


}



no_grafo **lista_amigos(grafo *g, char *nomeU, int *n)
{

    if(g== NULL || nomeU == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(n == NULL)
        return NULL;

    no_grafo **lista = (no_grafo**)calloc(g->tamanho,sizeof(no_grafo*));
    if(lista == NULL)  return NULL;

    int contador=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < g->tamanho;i++){
        if(strcmp(g->nos[i]->nome_user,nomeU) == 0){
            for(int j = 0; j < g->nos[i]->tamanho; j++){
                if(g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]->peso_ligacao > 3){
                    // potencial amigo
                    for(int t = 0; t < g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]->destino->tamanho; t++){
                        if((g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]->destino->ligacoes[t]->peso_ligacao > 3) && (g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]->destino->ligacoes[t]->destino == g->nos[i])){
                            lista[contador] = g->nos[i]->ligacoes[j]->destino;
                            n[0]++;
                            contador++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lista = (no_grafo**)realloc(lista,contador*sizeof(no_grafo*));
    return lista;


}




no_grafo ** identifica_ciclo(grafo *g, char *nomeU, int M, int *n)
{

    if(g== NULL || nomeU == NULL)
        return NULL;



    return NULL;

}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "tabdispersao.h"
#include "grafo.h"
#include "stnova.h"


/* DEFINES E VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS UTEIS PARA OS TESTES */
#define MAX_LINHA 1024
#define TAB_MSG 17
#define TAB_MSG1 997

/* VERIFICACOES IMPLEMENTADAS */
int verifica_tabela_existe(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;

    int t=tabela_existe(td, "FERNANDO");
    if(t!=0)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente inexistente): tabela_existe deu diferente de 0 (ERRO)\n");
       er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente inexistente): tabela_existe deu 0 (OK)\n");

    t=tabela_existe(td, "ANA");
    if(t!=7)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente que existe): tabela_existe deu diferente de 7 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente que existe): tabela_existe deu 7 (OK)\n"); 

    return er;
}

int verifica_tabela_listagem(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;

    mensagem** t=tabela_listagem(td, "FERNANDO");
    if(t==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente inexistente): tabela_listagem deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    } else
    {
       if(t[0]!=NULL)
        {
            printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente inexistente): tabela_listagem a primeira posição deu diferente de NULL (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
        }
        else
            printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente inexistente): tabela_listagem a primeira posição deu NULL (OK)\n");
    }



   free(t);

   t=tabela_listagem(td, "ANA");
   if(t==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente inexistente): tabela_listagem deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else { 
        int i=0;
        if (t)
        {
            while (t[i]!=NULL)
            { 
                i++;
            }

            if(i!=7)
            {
                printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente que existe): tabela_listagem deu diferente de 7 mensagens(ERRO)\n");
                er++;
            }
            else
                printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente que existe): tabela_listagem deu 7 mensagens(OK)\n"); 

            i=0;

            free(t);
        }
    }
    return er;
}


int verifica_ligacao2(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;
    int totMsg[2]={0};
    ligacao2(td,"LUIS","FERNANDO",totMsg);
    if(totMsg[0]!=-1 || totMsg[1]!=-1)
    {
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Os remetentes sao inexistente): ligacao2 deu diferente de -1 -1 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Os remetentes sao inexistente): ligacao2 deu -1 -1 (OK)\n");

    ligacao2(td,"PEDRO","MARIA",totMsg);


 if(totMsg[0]!=0 || totMsg[1]!=1)
    {
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Remetentes existentes): ligacao2 deu diferente de 0 1 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Remetentes existentes): ligacao2 deu 0 1 (OK)\n");
    return er;
}


int verifica_criaGrafo(tabela_dispersao* td,grafo **g)
{
    int er=0;
    *g=criaGrafo(td);

    if (*g)
    {

        if((*g)->tamanho!=7)
        {
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu diferente de 7 (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
        }
        else
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu 7 (OK)\n");
    } else

        {
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
        } 

    return er;

}
int verifica_lista_amigos(grafo *g)
{
    int er=0;
    int n=0;
    no_grafo **nos=lista_amigos(g, "PEDRO", &n);

    if(n!=0)
    {
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(sem amigos): lista_amigos deu diferente de 0(ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(sem amigos): lista_amigos deu 0 (OK)\n");
    free(nos);

  nos=lista_amigos(g, "ANA", &n);

    if(n==0)
    {
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(sem amigos): lista_amigos deu  0 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
   if (strcmp(nos[0]->nome_user,"MAFALDA"))
    {
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(com amigos): lista_amigos deu diferente da amiga MAFALDA (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(com amigos): lista_amigos deu a amiga MAFALDA (OK)\n");

    free(nos);

    return er;

}



int verifica_identifica_ciclo(grafo *g)
{
    int er=0;
    no_grafo **nosciclo;
    int r;

    nosciclo=identifica_ciclo(g, "MARIA", 4, &r);


    if(nosciclo==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else if(r!=4)
    {
        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu um numero de nos diferente de 4 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu um numero de nos igual a 4 (OK)\n");
        printf("Os no´s foram: ");
        for (int i=0;i<r-1;i++)
            printf("[%d %s] : ",i+1,nosciclo[i]->nome_user);
        printf("[%d %s]\n",r,nosciclo[r-1]->nome_user);
    }
    free(nosciclo);

    return er;

}


int verifica_st_remove(estrutura *st)
{
    int er=0;



    elemento *el=st_remove(st,"ANA");
    elemento *aux;

    if(el==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_st_remove(): st_remove deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else 
    {   char amigo[TAMANHO_CHAVE];
        int i=0;
        if (strcmp(el->msg->remetente,"ANA")==0)
            strcpy(amigo,el->msg->destinatario);

        while (el)
        {
            i++;

            aux=el->proximo;
        if (el->msg->texto)
          free(el->msg->texto);
        free(el->msg);
        free(el);
        el=aux;

        }
       if((i==4) && (strcmp(amigo,"MAFALDA")==0))
        {
            printf("...verifica_st_remove(): st_remove removeu a amiga MAFALDA com 4 mensagens (OK)\n");

        }
        else
           { 
            printf("...verifica_st_remove():  st_remove não removeu a amiga MAFALDA com 4 mensagens (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
           }
    }


    return er;

}
 /*================================================= */

int verifica_tabela_existe1(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;

    int t=tabela_existe(td, "JACK");

     if(t!=778)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente que existe): tabela_existe deu diferente de 778 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_tabela_existe(Remetente que existe): tabela_existe deu 778 (OK)\n"); 

    return er;
}

int verifica_tabela_listagem1(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;

    mensagem** t=tabela_listagem(td, "JAKE");

   if(t==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente inexistente): tabela_listagem deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else { 
        int i=0;
        if (t)
        {
            while (t[i]!=NULL)
            { 
                i++;
            }

            if(i!=521)
            {
                printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente que existe): tabela_listagem deu diferente de 521 mensagens(ERRO)\n");
                er++;
            }
            else
                printf("...verifica_tabela_listagem(Remetente que existe): tabela_listagem deu 521 mensagens(OK)\n"); 


            free(t);
        }
    }
    return er;
}

int verifica_ligacao21(tabela_dispersao* td)
{
    int er=0;
    int totMsg[2]={0};
    ligacao2(td,"CATES","HAMMOND",totMsg);




 if(totMsg[0]!=135 || totMsg[1]!=109)
    {
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Remetentes existentes): ligacao2 deu diferente de 135 e 109 (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_ligacao2(Remetentes existentes): ligacao2 deu 135 109 (OK)\n");
    return er;
}


int verifica_criaGrafo1(tabela_dispersao* td,grafo **g)
{
    int er=0;
    *g=criaGrafo(td);

    if (*g)
    {

        if((*g)->tamanho!=1545)
        {
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu diferente de 1545 nós (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
        }
        else
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu 1545 nós (OK)\n");
    } else

        {
            printf("...verifica_criaGrafo(numero de nos): criaGrafo deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
            er++;
        } 

    return er;

}

int verifica_lista_amigos1(grafo *g)
{
    int er=0;
    int n=0,j,i,correto=0,resultado=0;
    no_grafo **nos=lista_amigos(g, "WOMAN", &n);
    char nomes[6][14]={"CHESS PLAYER","JACK","JACOB","JOE","MILES","ROB"};
    if(n==0)
    {

       er++;
    }
    else
   {    
       resultado=1;
       for (i=0;i<n;i++)
       {   
           correto=0;
           for(j=0;j<6;j++)
           {

               if (strcmp(nos[i]->nome_user,nomes[j])==0)
                {
                    correto=1;
                    break;
                }
           }
           if (correto==0) 
            {
                resultado=0;
            }
       }

       if (!resultado)
    {
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(com amigos): lista_amigos deu pelos menos um diferente ""CHESS PLAYER"",""JACK"",""JACOB"",""JOE"",""MILES"",""ROB"" (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else
        printf("...verifica_lista_amigos(com amigos): lista_amigos deu ""CHESS PLAYER"",""JACK"",""JACOB"",""JOE"",""MILES"",""ROB"" (OK)\n");
   }
    free(nos);

    return er;

}


int verifica_identifica_ciclo1(grafo *g)
{
     int er=0;
     no_grafo **nosciclo;
    int r;

    nosciclo=identifica_ciclo(g, "ERNEST",8, &r);


    if(nosciclo==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else if(r>=3 && r<=8)

    {
        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu um numero de nos está entre 3 e 8 (OK)\n");
        printf("Os no´s foram: ");
        for (int i=0;i<r-1;i++)
            printf("[%d %s] : ",i+1,nosciclo[i]->nome_user);
        printf("[%d %s]\n",r,nosciclo[r-1]->nome_user);

    }
    else
    {  

        printf("...verifica_identifica_ciclo(com ciclo): identifica_ciclo deu um numero de nos que não está entre 3 e 8 (ERRO)\n");
        printf("Os no´s foram: ");
        for (int i=0;i<r-1;i++)
            printf("[%d %s] : ",i+1,nosciclo[i]->nome_user);
        printf("[%d %s]\n",r,nosciclo[r-1]->nome_user);
        er++;
    }
    free(nosciclo);

    return er;

}

int verifica_st_remove1(estrutura *st)
{
    int er=0;
    clock_t start_t, end_t;
    start_t = clock(); 
    elemento *el=st_remove(st,"HELEN");
    end_t = clock();
    elemento *aux;

    if(el==NULL)
    {
        printf("...verifica_st_remove(): st_remove deu NULL (ERRO)\n");
        er++;
    }
    else 
    {   char amigo[TAMANHO_CHAVE];
        int i=0;
         if (strcmp(el->msg->remetente,"HELEN")==0)
               strcpy(amigo,el->msg->destinatario);

        while (el)
        {
            i++;

            aux=el->proximo;
        if (el->msg->texto)
            free(el->msg->texto);
        free(el->msg);
        free(el);
        el=aux;

        }
       if((i==67) && (strcmp(amigo,"CALVIN")==0))
        {
            printf("...verifica_st_remove(): st_remove removeu a amiga CALVIN com 67 mensagens (OK)\n");
            printf("\tTempo a remover: %.8f\n", (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        else
           { 
            printf("...verifica_st_remove():  st_remove removeu a amiga %s com %d mensagens devia ser (CALVIN,67) (ERRO)\n",amigo,i);

            er++;
           }
    }


    return er;

}

 /*================================================= */


int main()
{

    int errCount=0, err;
    char *fi= "dados.txt";


    tabela_dispersao* td;
    grafo *g;

    td=tabela_carrega(fi,TAB_MSG);



    printf("INICIO DOS TESTES: Boa sorte\n\n");
    printf("Teste com poucos utilizadores\n\n");

    err =  verifica_tabela_existe( td);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_tabela_existe\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_tabela_existe passou\n\n");
    }

     err =  verifica_tabela_listagem( td);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_tabela_listagem\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_tabela_listagem passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_ligacao2( td);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_ligacao2\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_ligacao2 passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_criaGrafo(td,&g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_criaGrafo\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_criaGrafo passou\n\n");
    }

      err =  verifica_lista_amigos(g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_lista_amigos\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_lista_amigos passou\n\n");
    }


    err =  verifica_identifica_ciclo(g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_identifica_ciclo\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_identifica_ciclo passou\n\n");
    }




    estrutura *st=st_nova();


    st_importa_tabela(st,td);



    err =  verifica_st_remove(st);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_st_remove\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_st_remove passou\n\n");
    }




    st_apaga(st); 
    tabela_apaga(td);
    grafo_apaga(g); 

/*================================================= */
/* Com um ficheiro maior */

    char *fic= "dataset_partA.txt";
    printf("Teste com muitos utilizadores\n\n");

    td=tabela_carrega(fic,TAB_MSG1);



    err =   verifica_tabela_existe1(td);


    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_st_remove\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_st_remove passou\n\n");
    }


    err =  verifica_tabela_listagem1( td);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_tabela_listagem\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_tabela_listagem passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_ligacao21( td);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_ligacao2\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_ligacao2 passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_criaGrafo1(td,&g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_criaGrafo\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_criaGrafo passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_lista_amigos1(g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_lista_amigos\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_lista_amigos passou\n\n");
    }

    err =  verifica_identifica_ciclo1(g);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_identifica_ciclo\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_identifica_ciclo passou\n\n");
    }
    st=st_nova();


    st_importa_tabela(st,td);




    err =  verifica_st_remove1(st);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("ERRO: %d erros encontrados em verifica_st_remove\n\n", err);
        errCount += err;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK: verifica_st_remove passou\n\n");
    } 

    st_apaga(st); 
    tabela_apaga(td);
    grafo_apaga(g);

    if (errCount == 0)
        printf("FIM DOS TESTES: Todos os testes passaram\n");
    else
        printf("FIM DOS TESTES: Foram encontrados %d ERROS no total\n", errCount);

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: Can you show your malloc call code?

Comment: Sure im going to edit sory. Its a little bit big , but i think is easy to find

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
g->nos = (no_grafo **)malloc(sizeof(no_grafo*))`
```

1. the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.
2. since `no_grafo` is a `typedef`struct and you want to allocate enough memory for the struct, then remove the `*` from the parameter:  `sizeof(no_grafo*)` should be: `sizeof( no_grafo )`
3. Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call:

   perror( "malloc failed" );

which will output to `stderr` both the error message "malloc failed" and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.